# Executing procedure with varchar parameter, passed into OPENROWSET, error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I'm working on procedure, which uses `OPENROWSET`.
I need to pass 1 varchar parameter into it. That's how I've decided to do that:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetId]
@designatio varchar
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @SQLStr varchar(max)=
    'select * FROM OPENROWSET(''SQLOLEDB'',''SQLSERVER'';''sss'';''sss''
    ,''select *
        from db.dbo.table)
        where DESIGNATIO = ''' + @designatio + ')'

EXECUTE(@SQLStr)
END
```

Everything is OK, but I get error when execute it:

```
exec GetId 'П-11792.00'
```

> Incorrect syntax near 'П'

I've tried to cast passing parameter hard, so the error was the same, but

> Incorrect syntax near 'П-11792.00'

Please, tell me, where am I wrong.

Comment: The procedure declaration is `GetId` yet the example you give is `GetSearchId`, is this a typo?

Comment: @FilipeNóbrega Yes, sorry for that)

Comment: If you replace `varchar` with `nvarchar` and define some size for parameter (like `nvarchar(100)`), then replace all strings with unicode ones (`''` -> `N''`) does something improve? And don't forget to sanitize input string - at least replace apostrophes with double ones.

Comment: As I've understood you right, you would write this: DECLARE @SQLStr varchar(max)=
  'select * FROM OPENROWSET(N''SQLOLEDBN'',N''SQLSERVERN'';N''saN'';N''wmprnxugnspvfrgpagejucN''
  ,N''select *
   from Search.dbo.DOCLIST with(nolock))
   where DESIGNATIO = N''' + designatio + ')' , and replace varchar with nvarachar. But that doesn't help

Comment: You don't have enough quotes. Remember, the query in `OPENROWSET` is itself quoted and you're constructing it dynamically, so you need four quotes to get two quotes to end up with one quote in the final query. (And you're missing the closing quotes.) Always try to build the query up in layers, bottom-up, replacing quotes systematically as you go up a level. That way you don't accidentally miss one. `PRINT`ing what you construct is also always a good idea.

Comment: Also, where possible, see if `EXECUTE .. AT` with a linked server is an option, because unlike `OPENROWSET`, it does support parameters (`EXECUTE ('SELECT * FROM db.dbo.table WHERE DESIGNATIO = ?', @designatio) AT LinkedServerName`), saving a whole bunch of quoting hassles.

Comment: `@designatio varchar` That is a single character parameter - a common mistake. ALWAYS define the length of any variable length datatype.

Comment: Thank you, all, I see, that the problem might be in quotes amount, but I still cannot find, where exactly.

Comment: The first thing you should do is print your SQL and inspect it. Don't try and debug it without actually looking at it

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetId]
@designatio varchar
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @SQLStr varchar(max)=
    'select * FROM OPENROWSET(''SQLOLEDB'',''SQLSERVER'';''sss'';''sss''
    ,''select *
        from db.dbo.table)
        where DESIGNATIO = ''''' + @designatio + ''''' '')'

EXECUTE(@SQLStr)
END
```

The problem was in understanding, that string value in query must have own quotes, so if it is already in double quotes, it must be in 4 quotes + own quotes.

Comment: Note that this will still (silently) fail if you pass a `@designation` of more than a single character, be sure to correct that. It's a [bad habit to kick](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

Comment: Oh, thank you, I see that. I've posted the procedure in such view, because there have been a lot of tries to make it right before I've decided to ask.